# Error Handling in Interpreter Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, exception, effective-c++, interpreter-pattern

Assume I want to add up either arabic numbers (1+2) or roman numbers (I+II) and I use an interpreter pattern that looks something like this:

(code derived from here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Interpreter)

```
struct Expression {
    virtual int interpret() = 0;
};

class ArabicNumber : public Expression {
private:
    int number;
public: 
    ArabicNumber(int number)       { this->number = number; }
    int interpret(Map variables)  { return number; }
}

class RomanNumber : public Expression {
private:
    string number;
public: 
    RomanNumber(string number)       { this->number = number; }
    int interpret(Map variables)  {
        //somehow convert the roman number string to an int
    }
}

class Plus : public Expression {
  Expression* leftOperand;
   Expression* rightOperand;
public: 
    Plus(Expression* left, Expression* right) { 
        leftOperand = left; 
        rightOperand = right;
    }
    ~Plus(){ 
        delete leftOperand;
        delete rightOperand;
    }

    int interpret(Map variables)  { 
        return leftOperand->interpret(variables) + rightOperand->interpret(variables);
    }
};
```

How do I ensure that the erroneous query (1+II) is handled properly? The only solution I could think of was to somehow use casting but that doesn't sound like an elegant solution. Or should the pattern not be used that way?

Of course, one option would be to write two separate functions for this, but I'm curious if it could be done in one because I would like to use this pattern for a more complex context free grammar.

Edit: My problem is also described [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=ZIjMcB0V2agC&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=interpreter%20pattern%20error%20handling&source=bl&ots=4UsJqctEvM&sig=HXfu7FasSrFt66Xw3rupVCeereA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXvP2QmanKAhVpp3IKHVqBAJkQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=interpreter%20pattern%20error%20handling&f=false). I quote the relevant section:

> However, introducing a language and its accompanying grammar also requires fairly extensive error checking for misspelled terms or misplaced grammatical elements.

So my **main question**: How to best design that extensive error checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to only permit adding roman numerals or arabic ones, but not a mix? If a mix would be OK, your code would just work (assuming you write the actual parsing code for Roman-to-int you left out up there). If you don't want to permit a mix, you'd need to add a verification step before calling interpret on both arguments in Plus().

E.g you could `dynamic_cast<ArabicNumber>` both operands and if one is NULL fail, if both are NULL try `dynamic_cast<RomanNumber>` instead. Usually testing for a class's type is a code smell, but here you're validating, so it's OK.

Another approach would be to give each `Expression` a `CanBeConvertedToType()` method, then have a switch statement in that function that checks a constant representing the given type to the type of the result of the given `Expression`. This would be a bit more future-safe as it allows you to have different `Expression` subclasses that all return the same type, without having to change the type-checking code to check for each class that is valid when you add a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really don't want to allow mixing. I don't want to just convert because I want to turn this into a language grammar (think subject-verb-object ordering is ok any other isn't), so I will use the `dynamic_cast` idea. I was unsure if it would be ok (like you said, testing for a class type smells) but I think that's exactly what I want to do here: validate that the passed string conforms to my grammar.